# Display details of value in localstorage from a linked HTML5 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm creating a site where you can create and store info about upcoming appointments.  The main page shows three upcoming appointments.
What I have now is a HTML5 element that contains only two key values such as "Title:" and "Location:".  When you click on the element I would like to show a more detailed view of the information on a separate html page such as :  "Title:"  "Location:" "Date:"  "City, State" .

How is this done?  Also, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Your explanation is not enough to get an appropriate answer. but about `localStorage` you can save a complete object _(stringified)_ in `localStorage` and then display any part of your data you want.

Comment: I am able to append the stringified object to a page displaying only a few key values but I'd like to link that particular object to another page to show a more "detailed" view of the rest of the key values.  Just like when you click on an appointment title in a calendar app and it shows even more detail on a separate page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029192/by-clicking-an-href-img-from-home-html-page-i-want-to-show-details-of-that-href

Comment: Can't use that solution guest271314 unfortunately because they're not using localstorage.